# How do you make a transition effect using requestAnimationFrame in js?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am good with my jumping system in my canvas, but it looks like I need some transition so it just not bounce from top and bounce back to bottom. Transition will help with the gravity effect while jumping.

Heres my code:

```
        function Game() {
            this.start = function() {
                generateObstacles();
                    for (var i = 0; i < Obstacles.length; i++) {
                    Paint.draw(Obstacles[i].x, Obstacles[i].y, Obstacles[i].width, Obstacles[i].height, Obstacles[i].color);
                }
                
                this.gravity();
            }
            this.stop = function() {
                
            }
            this.gravity = function() {
                let gravity = 0.098;
                let gravitySpeed = 0;
                
                function gravityEffect() {
                    gravitySpeed += gravity;
                    
                    Paint.erase(myPiece.x, myPiece.y, myPiece.width, myPiece.height);
                    myPiece.y += gravitySpeed;
                    Paint.draw(myPiece.x, myPiece.y, myPiece.width, myPiece.height, myPiece.color);
                    
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(gravityEffect);
                }
                
                window.requestAnimationFrame(gravityEffect);
            }
            
            this.start();
        }
        function Paint() {
            this.draw = function(x, y, width, height, color) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            this.erase = function(x, y, width, height) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                ctx.closePath();
            }
        }
        function generateObstacles() {
            let x = myGame.width;
            let y = myGame.height;
            
            let maxWidth = 400;
            let minWidth = 100;
            let randomWidth = Random(maxWidth, minWidth);
            
            let maxHeight = 20;
            let minHeight = 5;
            let randomHeight = Random(maxHeight, minHeight);
            
            Obstacles.push(new Obstacle(x - randomWidth, y - randomHeight, randomWidth, randomHeight, true, 'green'));
        }
        function Random(max, min) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + 1 + min);
        }
        
        function Piece(x, y, width, height, behavior, color) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.behavior = behavior;
            this.color = color;
            Paint.draw(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.color);
        }
        function Obstacle(x, y, width, height, collidable, color) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.collidable = collidable;
            this.color = color;
        }
```

The erase function is not doing well when I am adding y in myPiece and its decimal. For example if its 0.098, the erase will not be accurate idk why, Its only accurate when I am adding integer on y.

Comment: Do you mean like a [star wipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wipe_(transition))?

Comment: No, I have created a gravity effect, but the problem is it creating some buggy lines. On the top, I think it is because of my draw and erase system, can you help me out?